# What is open source archive?

Tags: sony-xperia-sp

I just got notification from [Drippler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drippler.android.updates) app that open source archive is released for my device. This is the [Xperia SP v12.1.A.0.266 link](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/xperia-open-source-archives/open-source-archive-for-build-12-1-a-0-266/). I just want to know what is open source archive.

Comment: Rephrased so it doesn't get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open source archive is for the developers or ROM cooks. It contains files which can be used when building a kernel. This is mainly intended for experienced developers and not for normal phone users